# MYSQL fulltext - unexpected result

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a database of 80,000 rows and as I was testing out some FULLTEXT queries I encountered an unexpected result. I have removed stopwords from MYSQL and have set the minimum word length to 3.

When I do this query:

```
SELECT `sentence`, MATCH (`sentence`) AGAINST ('CAN YOU FLY') AS `relevance`
FROM `sentences`
WHERE MATCH (`sentence`) AGAINST ('CAN YOU FLY')
ORDER BY `relevance` DESC
```

It gives this result:

```
NO A FLY WITHOUT WINGS WOULD BE CALLED A WINGLESS | 10.623517036438
I CAN FLY                                         | 7.61278629302979
I CAN FLY :)                                      | 7.61278629302979
CAN YOU FLY?                                      | 7.61278629302979
THEY CAN FLY                                      | 7.61278629302979
YOU AM NOT FLY                                    | 7.61278629302979
CAN YOU FLY                                       | 7.61278629302979
HAVE YOU EVER SWALLOWED A FLY?                    | 7.52720737457275
I JUST WANNA FLY                                  | 7.52720737457275
```

Why has "NO A FLY WITHOUT WINGS WOULD BE CALLED A WINGLESS" got the highest relevance, it only contains one of the words... Also, how come "CAN YOU FLY" isn't at the top, it's an exact match.

I would like it to order by most matched keywords, then order by ones which are in order most, then order by fewest words. This would give the logical result:

```
CAN YOU FLY
CAN YOU FLY?
I CAN FLY
THEY CAN FLY
I CAN FLY :)
YOU AM NOT FLY
HAVE YOU EVER SWALLOWED A FLY?
I JUST WANNA FLY
NO A FLY WITHOUT WINGS WOULD BE CALLED A WINGLESS
```

Answer (score 1):

The formula used for calculations is available in [MySQL Internals Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/full-text-search.html):

> ```
> w = (log(dtf)+1)/sumdtf * U/(1+0.0115*U) * log((N-nf)/nf)
> ```
>
> where
>
> ```
> dtf     is the number of times the term appears in the document
> sumdtf  is the sum of (log(dtf)+1)'s for all terms in the same document
> U       is the number of Unique terms in the document
> N       is the total number of documents
> nf      is the number of documents that contain the term
> ```

The first text obviously has more content than than the others. And the formula relies greatly on `U`, the number of unique terms in the document.

By your comment, I would suggest to use [Boolean Fulltext Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//fulltext-boolean.html):

```
SELECT `sentence`, MATCH (`sentence`) AGAINST ('CAN YOU FLY' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS `relevance`
FROM `sentences`
WHERE MATCH (`sentence`) AGAINST ('CAN YOU FLY' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY `relevance` DESC
```

Comment: Wow, they seriously need to rethink their formula if not even the exact phrase is at the top of the results...

Comment: @user1970772 It's a full text search, it is not designed for 3 words documents. For example `FLY` is present in all the documents so it is not relevant, it increases the value of `nf`.

Comment: Do you know of any alternatives to FULLTEXT that will give me my desired result?

Comment: @user1970772 Never you clearly said what you want. Are you looking for an exact match? Rows with all the searched terms?

Comment: I would like it to order by most matched keywords, then order by ones which are in order most. I updated the OP to show the order it would result in then.